# Getting Start with Ember.js Router

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-old-router

I want to learn using Ember.js for my next project. So far I have read the documentation [here](http://emberjs.com/documentation/) but I saw no explanation about Router. Then I read the guide [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/outlets/) but I still don't understand how to use Router properly.
I tried using Router this way, I want 2 route:

1. `/login` which displays a button to enter the second route
2. `/home` which displays a button to enter the first route

This is just a very simple code to test using Router to switch between "pages".
I tried using this code but all I get is a blank page:

```
<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.0.0.beta.6.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/ember-1.0.pre.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var App = Ember.Application.create();

    App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend();
    App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend();

    App.LoginView = Ember.View.extend({
        templateName: 'login-page'
    });

    App.HomeView = Ember.View.extend({
        templateName: 'home-page'
    });

    App.router = Ember.Router.create({
        enableLogging: true,
        root: Ember.Route.extend({
            index: Ember.Route.extend({
                route: '/',
                redirectsTo: 'login'
            }),
            login: Ember.Route.extend({
                route: '/login',
                doLogin: Ember.Route.transitionTo('home'),
                connectOutlets: function (router) {
                    router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('login');
                }
            }),
            home: Ember.Route.extend({
                route: '/home',
                doLogout: Ember.Route.transitionTo('login'),
                connectOutlets: function (router) {
                    router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('home');
                }
            })
        })
    });
    App.initialize(App.router);
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="login-page">
    <h1>Login Page</h1>

    <button {{action doLogin}}>Login</button>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="home-page">
    <h1>Home Page</h1>

    <button {{action doLogout}}>Logout</button>
</script>
```

When I run this, the URL goes to `#/login` but it display nothing.
Does anyone can show me how to make the above code works? Why do I get a blank page?

Comment: what if you declare your App as a global (just removing var) ? Moreover, I think by searching a little on SO, there are now few router application snippets.

Comment: Where is your application view template? You connect to 'login' and 'home' outlets but where is it defined?

Comment: connectOutlet 'home' will use instance of 'HomeView', it's internal of Ember.js, removing var makes no difference, and I did search the other route example on SO yet still don't understand why the above code not working

Comment: I apologize, I've seen many questions about that, so I wanted only to be sure the answer was not already here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code: http://jsfiddle.net/jPn3H/

...updated with a brand new 'application' template hooked up to `App.ApplicationView`: http://jsfiddle.net/pauldechov/jPn3H/1/

The `.initialize()` function appends `App.ApplicationView` to `<body>` for you. Those `.connectOutlet(...)` calls won't do much of anything unless there's an `{{outlet}}` to connect. Hope that helps.

Comment: After days of struggling and getting nowhere, this was the first hello world example that (almost) simply worked for me!  The one catch was that I needed to wrap the initialize call:

$(function() { App.initialize(App.router); });

So that it wouldn't run until everything loaded.  Otherwise I got an error stating it couldn't find the application template.