# Start using Notify.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm working on a C# MVC (Visual Studio 2010) project and found [Notify.js](http://notifyjs.com/). I want to start using it but I don't know how. I added the downloaded content into my project and the `notify.js` script now shows under the `Scripts` folder, along with `modernizr.js`, `references.js`, `jquery-1.7.1.js`, etc..

I [saw](http://adodson.com/jquery-notify.js/#quicky) this is the method syntax:

```
$.notify( url Image, string Title, string Description);
```

An example:

```
$.notify("star.ico","Hello","This is a test");
```

But that's all I got, I don't know where or how to apply it.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here's the little bit of code I added to my `cshtml` file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/notify.js"></script>
```

But now I don't know how to use it.

Comment: That's a jQuery plugin just like a whole bunch out there. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you have your own code sample?

Comment: Yes @cr0ss, I just edited the question for you. And this is a question, as good as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825894/getting-start-with-ember-js-router?rq=1), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js?rq=1) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854539/getting-started-with-doctrine)

Comment: Are you at all familiar with jQuery?

Comment: This is the link for you: http://spyrestudios.com/simple-guide-how-to-get-started-with-jquery/
After that (adding the javascript file and creating the `hello world` script inside `$(document).ready(...)`, you need to add `notify.js` like you are already doing. Only after that you need to learn the API

Comment: Check out this one too http://blog.createbrilliance.com/blog/getting-started-with-jquery-hello-world/

Answer (score 0):

Go through their site. Whenever you want to use a plugin, the best place to start is their website. They will always have some example and documentation.

http://notifyjs.com/

I found a good link for you. [How to use a jquery plugin](http://andreaslagerkvist.com/how-to-include-a-jquery-plug-in/)

Comment: That's not an answer since that's not an actual question.

Comment: @AbhinavRanjan, I have obviously done that already. I'm looking for someone who already used it that might help me by sharing his experience, like: add the library, create a script section on your chtml, etc